# R cannot load package forecast due to namespace error

Tags: r, namespaces, package

I tried installing all the dependant packages and also tried another repo source as recommended in another post here.

R version 3.2.0 x64

```
install.packages("fracdiff")
install.packages("Rcpp")
install.packages("RcppArmadillo") 
install.packages("colorspace")
install.packages("forecast", dep=T)
install.packages("forecast", repos=c("http://cran.rstudio.com"),dep=T)
library("forecast")
```

then I get

```
Loading required package: zoo 
Attaching package: ‘zoo’
The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:
as.Date, as.Date.numeric

Loading required package: timeDate
Error : .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'forecast', details:
call: fun(libname, pkgname)
error: 4 arguments passed to .Internal(nchar) which requires 3
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘forecast’ was built under R version 3.2.1 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘forecast’
```

sessionInfo()

```
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] Hmisc_3.16-0       ggplot2_1.0.1      Formula_1.2-1      survival_2.38-1    lattice_0.20-31    zoo_1.7-12         timeSeries_3012.99 timeDate_3012.100 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.11.6         cluster_2.0.1       magrittr_1.5        MASS_7.3-41         splines_3.2.0       forecast_6.1        munsell_0.4.2      
 [8] colorspace_1.2-6    quadprog_1.5-5      stringr_1.0.0       plyr_1.8.3          tools_3.2.0         nnet_7.3-9          parallel_3.2.0     
[15] gtable_0.1.2        latticeExtra_0.6-26 tseries_0.10-34     digest_0.6.8        gridExtra_0.9.1     RColorBrewer_1.1-2  reshape2_1.4.1     
[22] acepack_1.3-3.3     rpart_4.1-9         fracdiff_1.4-2      stringi_0.4-1       scales_0.2.5        foreign_0.8-63      proto_0.3-10
```

Comment: I suspect a version mismatch. You should make sure you have updated all your packages to their current versions (and do stop using 'T' for `TRUE`). And if all that fails I suggest posting output from `sessionInfo()`

Comment: DId that but it didnt help

Comment: @BondedDust I aded sessionInfo()

Comment: Maybe try this in a clean R session. You have a ton of packages attached.

Comment: I tried to reproduce. I get no message about either loading timeDate or the error you see. I do get a message about loading pkg:zoo. The package loads and announces its version number. Try restarting as suggested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried to reproduce. I get no message about either loading timeDate or the error you see. I do get a message about loading pkg:zoo. The package loads and announces its version number. Try updating to R version 3.2.1, since that is where a new argument to `nchar` was introduced:

```
new$Text[ grep("nchar", news$Text) ]
```

`• nchar(x, *) and nzchar(x) gain a new argument keepNA which governs how the result for NAs in x is determined. For the R 3.2.x series, the default remains FALSE which is fully back compatible. From R 3.3.0, the default will change to keepNA = NA and you are advised to consider this for code portability.`

Comment: got exactly the same problem. upgrading from R 3.2.0 to 3.2.1 solved this.

Comment: Got "error: 4 arguments passed to .Internal(nchar) which requires 3" trying to use the `raster` package and upgraded from 3.2.0 to 3.2.1 to resolve this as well.

Comment: That comment appears to be another question since the error message is different and the package as well. You also will need to post code that creates the error rather than vaguely stating  you are "trying to use the raster package." Follow the example above ....  post code , complete error transcript, and sessionInfo().